# add calculated column for date in olap cube

Tags: olap, olap-cube

I am having same problem as in below link:

[SQL Analysis Services OLAP TIME dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305351/sql-analysis-services-olap-time-dimension/14020884#14020884)

Can I get steps to add new calculate member for date dimension in OLAP cube?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding new calculated member for date dimension in OLAP cube, you can convert your datetime field in fact to be only date to match dimension. For eg:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '10/23/2016', 101) -- mm/dd/yyyy
```